# jquery clone() with html() is not a function

Tags: jquery, html, clone

Creating my own photo gallery I wanted to load small picture to bigger div to enlarge it. First, I use to html(), but it delete main (small) photo, or do nothing (i found several few solution how to use html() without delating main data, but non of tchem work). So I tryed to use clone(). But then I try combine it with html() it give me error: this.clone is not a function.  Again I try to found solution, but nothing work.
Here is my code with solutions that I tryed to use and effects:

```
<script>
var GallObj={
    img:<?php echo json_encode($GetImg->jsonData); ?>,
    imgIndex:new Number, //storage data about index of enlaging picture
}

var showAllImg = $.map(GallObj.img, function(val, i) {
    return "<img src='gallery/"+val+"' class='smallimg'>";
});

$("#gallCont").html(showAllImg.join(""));

$('.smallimg').click(function(){
    GallObj.imgIndex=$('.smallimg').index(this);

   //it work, but I need change it and use html() because it doesn't change one loaded photo to new loaded photo of course:
   $(this).clone().appendTo($('#picture')); 

   // this two removed clicked oryginalny picture and I don't want it:
   $('#picture').html(this)
   $('#picture').html(this).html(); 

   //this.clone is not a function error:
   elm=this.clone();
   $('#picture').html(elm);

   //this.clone is not a function error:       
   $('#picture').html(this.clone());

   //do nothing:
   $('#picture').clone().html(this);

   //do nothing:
   var value=$(this).html();
   $("#picture").html(value);


   $('#mask, #fixed, #picture, #close').css('display','block');
   $('#mask').animate({'width':'100%','height':screen.height +100, opacity:'0.5'});
   $('#picture').animate({width:'900'});
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 1500);
})
</script>
```

Please, help me and explain what I did wrong...

Comment: You have several places where you're using `clone()` and `html()`. j08691 has answered why you're receiving the error, but I must say, your code is quite confusing. You shouldn't be calling `html()` with `this`; [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html) is meant to be called with, well, HTML, as a string (or a function, but not an HTML element or a jQuery object).

Comment: I use clone() and html() in several places only here, to show solutions that I tryied to use and they didn't work. So what instead od html() I should to use in my code?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. If you want to replace the contents of the "#picture" with the element, [`empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) followed by [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) would be your best bet. But really, you should take a look at some tutorials on jQuery, and maybe read the documentation.

Comment: I want to load cliked img object to div#picture. So I think html() is ok?

Comment: Obviously it's your choice. If I saw one of my programmers passing something that's not a string or function to `html()`, I'd make them change it. Just because it works now, doesn't mean it will work in a later version of jQuery.

Answer (score 6):

In `this.clone()`, `.clone()` is a jQuery function but you're trying to use it on `this` which is plain JavaScript.

Try `$(this).clone()` instead.